# Crawling this website to grab lyrics?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

I am trying to crawl this website for song lyrics:

```
http://www.mldb.org/aza-A.html
```

Here is the code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,sys
seed = "http://www.mldb.org/aza-A.html"
ROOT = "http://www.mldb.org/"

def gather_links(seed,already_visisted):
  response = requests.get(seed)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
  table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'thelist'})
  to_visit=[]
  start = "<a href=\""
  end = ">"
  for row in table.findAll("a"):
    stringed = str(row)
    ended = stringed.find(end)
    cleaned = ROOT+stringed[len(start):ended]
    if (cleaned not in already_visisted) or (cleaned not in to_visit):
      to_visit.append(cleaned)
  already_visisted.append(seed)
  return list(set(to_visit))
  #visted.append(seed)
global_to_visit = [seed]
already_visited = []

for link in global_to_visit:
  global_to_visit += gather_links(link,already_visited)
  print len(global_to_visit),len(already_visited),link
```

I think is reaching the lyrics page and now I just have to crawl those pages for required text but I am not sure whether this is the "best" way to achieve the purpose.

Comment: Have you tried a dedicated web scrapping tool such as scrapy? If you're planning on crawling multiple pages then that may be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a different website (LyricWikia), but I wrote a simple [command line tool](https://github.com/rasbt/datacollect/blob/master/collect_lyrics/) in Python to download Lyrics from there. Although they don't have all the lyrics in the world, the most songs can be found there.
I have written it as `class` so you can import it into your code instead of running it from the command line if you need.

This would be the relevant part,

```
import urllib
import re
import lxml.html
import unicodedata
import os


class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, artist, title):
        self.artist = self.__format_str(artist)
        self.title = self.__format_str(title)
        self.url = None
        self.lyric = None

    def __format_str(self, s):
        # remove paranthesis and contents
        s = s.strip()
        try:
            # strip accent
            s = ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
                         if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
        except:
            pass
        s = s.title()
        return s

    def __quote(self, s):
         return urllib.parse.quote(s.replace(' ', '_'))

    def __make_url(self):
        artist = self.__quote(self.artist)
        title = self.__quote(self.title)
        artist_title = '%s:%s' %(artist, title)
        url = 'http://lyrics.wikia.com/' + artist_title
        self.url = url

    def update(self, artist=None, title=None):
        if artist:
            self.artist = self.__format_str(artist)
        if title:
            self.title = self.__format_str(title)

    def lyricwikia(self):
        self.__make_url()
        try:
            doc = lxml.html.parse(self.url)
            lyricbox = doc.getroot().cssselect('.lyricbox')[0]
        except IOError:
            self.lyric = ''
            return
        lyrics = []

        for node in lyricbox:
            if node.tag == 'br':
                lyrics.append('\n')
            if node.tail is not None:
                lyrics.append(node.tail)
        self.lyric =  "".join(lyrics).strip()    
        return self.lyric
```

And you can use it like

```
song = Song(artist='Bob Dylan', title='Blowing in the wind')
lyr = song.lyricwikia()
print(lyr)
```